# Ajax (in Laravel project) is not working on a page, while working same code on another page

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I am new in coding. Having some problem in **Ajax** code in **Laravel 5.2** project.

THE CODE IS RUNNING ON REGISTRATION PAGE, BUT NOT ON ANOTHER PAGE, ON WHICH I NEED TO DO.

Please help me.

**The Routes -**

```
Route::post('like-article',['as'=>'like_article','uses'=>'LikeController@likeArticle']);
```

**The controller -**

```
public function likeArticle(){
    $like_article_id = trim(Input::get('like_article_id'));
    $article_count = DB::table('articles')
            ->where('id',$like_article_id)
            ->count();
    if($article_count){
        return "1";
    }
    else{
        return "0";
    }                
}
```

**Ajax part -**

```js
$("#like_thumb_up_img").click(function() {
    //alert('Alert !');
    $.ajax({
        url : 'like-article',
        type:'post',
        dataType:'HTML',
        data : {like_article_id:$('#like_article_id').attr('value')},
        success:function(result){
            //alert(result);
            if(result=="1")
            {
                $('#like_show_div').html('Got Article !');
            }
            else if(result=="0")
            {
                $('#like_show_div').html('Not Found !');
            }
        }
    })
})
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <input type="hidden" id="like_article_id" value="{{$article[0]->id}}">
    <img id="like_thumb_up_img" class="img-responsive custom_margin_auto custom_margin_top_bottom_5" src="{{URL::asset('system_images/thumb_up.png')}}" alt="Thumb up">
</div>
<div id="like_show_div" class="row">
</div>
```

Thank you in advance for finding the bug.

Comment: can you post the code that isn't working? From what I can see, this is the working code... right?

Comment: There's a possibility the url should be `url : '/like-article',` depending on the URL of the current page.

Comment: If you are using jQuery in your snippet please include it in the snippet.

Comment: No console error. If url changed to '/like-article' then console error arises. Yes, jquery is already added - <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="{{asset('js/jquery-2.2.4.min.js')}}"></script>

Comment: Check you network tab in chrome and see what is says when you execute your ajax request. First thing I see is you are missing your applications csrf token. https://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#csrf-protection

If this is the case I'll post an answer.

Comment: on the registration page I checked without token - that was working. On current working page, I used token "<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="<?php echo csrf_token(); ?>">" - and checked, but not working.....Is here any other way to include token? By the way, when I click on #like_thumb_up_img it shows in consol - I just found - POST http://localhost/wikiako/public/article-view/like-article 405 (Method Not Allowed)

Comment: There is a typo in your ajax. Look at type: 'post' and replace it with: method: 'post' EDIT: nevermind, type is an alias for method.

Comment: I used "method:'post'," - but same error - "POST http://localhost/wikiako/public/article-view/like-article 405 (Method Not Allowed)"

Comment: I am surprised - To check the code - the same code, nothing changed even in line, I used on another Registration page, is working fine. But is not working on this page........... !!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Add an error handler to the Ajax call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your url using the `url()` or `secure_url()`(if you have a ssl certificate) function

```
$("#like_thumb_up_img").click(function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 var like_article = $('#like_article_id').attr('value');
$.ajax({
    url : "{{url('like-article')}}",
    type:'post',
    dataType:'HTML',
    data : {like_article_id:like_article},
    success:function(result){
        //alert(result);
        if(result=="1")
        {
            $('#like_show_div').html('Got Article !');
        }
        else if(result=="0")
        {
            $('#like_show_div').html('Not Found !');
        }
         }
       })
      })
```

Comment: GREAT !!! It's working......... secure_url() is not working, but url() is working perfectly. Special thanks to madalin ivascu, and thanks to all of you who tried to solve this issue.

Comment: don't forget to check the checkbox to accept the answer :p

Comment: ooooo thak you, I didn't know this, 1st time using this platform. Checked...... Thank you once again.

Answer (score 0):

in your ajax part

```
$("#like_thumb_up_img").click(function() {
//alert('Alert !');
 var like_article = $('#like_article_id').attr('value');
$.ajax({
    url : 'like-article',
    type:'post',
    dataType:'HTML',
    data : {like_article_id:like_article},
    success:function(result){
        //alert(result);
        if(result=="1")
        {
            $('#like_show_div').html('Got Article !');
        }
        else if(result=="0")
        {
            $('#like_show_div').html('Not Found !');
        }
         }
       })
      })
```

finally if the error is 500 you should add _token to your post method

Answer (score 0):

it must be remember that when you send ajax request inside laravel always use this code to prevent csrf token error :

```
headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
                }
```